# How can I create a generator which combines two generators' data, element-wise?

Tags: python, generator

I have a generator which iterates over strings, eg `['apple', 'banana', orange']`.
I have an additional generator which iterates over a different set of strings, eg `['car', 'truck', 'bike']`

I'd like to create a generator, that when iterated over, returns the following:
`'applecar', 'bananatruck', 'orangebike'`.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Use the `zip` function: `[a+b for a,b in zip(list1, list2)]`

Comment: @Mike67, you have permission to post answers--no need to put it in a comment

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but make sure to think about what you want to happen if the two are different lengths.

```
def generator(a, b):
    for a_element, b_element in zip(a,b):
        yield a_element + b_element
```

or more compactly:

```
new_gen = ( a_element + b_element for a_element,b_element in zip(a,b) )
```